# Add proxy information and basic auth to the resttemplate using httpClient

Tags: spring, proxy, basic-authentication, resttemplate

My development environment is behind a proxy so i need to set the proxy information to the rest template, that's all good when i use a HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory and set the proxy setting in the httpClient and set it in the template.

But now i have a rest service that needs basic auth. And to set the basic auth credentials, i need to set them in the httpClient on the rest template. But i see that the getparams method in the httpClient is depricated,  so i can't just update the existing client in the template, and if i create a new httpclient object,  i will overwrite the proxy info that were set during the application bootstrapping.

So is there some way that i could extract the httpClient from the rest template and update it?  Or is there  any other way to tackle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configure the [`httpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) as follows:

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("hostname", 80, "http");
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy", 12345);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setProxy(proxy)
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpclient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

See also [HttpClient Examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

Comment: Thanks @fateddy I finally went with this in combination with spring "@profile" config to create the necessary rest templates for dev & non dev environments.

Comment: doesn't work, keep giving same error

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me i work around the above and finally make it work with small modifications.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHost proxy =null;
    RequestConfig config=null;
    String credentials = this.env.getProperty("uname") + ":" + this.env.getProperty("pwd");
    String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());

    Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    headers.add(header);

    if(Boolean.valueOf(env.getProperty("proxyFlag"))){
        proxy = new HttpHost(this.env.getProperty("proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("proxyPort")), "http");
        config= RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    }else{
        config= RequestConfig.custom().build();
    }


    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

    return restTemplate;
```